# c++ shared_ptr & memcpy errors

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have decided to move to modern c++ practices, and I'v tried to adapt my old code to make use of smart pointers. I have a packet class that holds the packet data, along side some other variables.

```
class Packet
{
public:
    Packet(int connId, std::shared_ptr<char[]> buff, size_t pLen) 
        : connID(connId), packetLen(pLen)
    {
        buffer = buff;
    }

    Packet(){}

    int connID;
    size_t packetLen;
    std::shared_ptr<char[]> buffer;
};
```

And I have a test function that creates and inserts data into the new allocated buffer.

```
std::vector<Packet> packetV;

void createPacket()
{
    std::shared_ptr<char[]> data = std::make_shared<char[]>(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t byte = 5;
        memcpy(*data.get() + i, &byte, sizeof(uint8_t));
    }

    packetV.push_back(Packet(1, data, 5*sizeof(uint8_t)));
}

//(Main function)
void main()
{
    std::string input;
    do
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == "packet") createPacket();
        else if (input == "exit") input.clear();
        else if (input == "empty") packetV.clear();
        else if (input == "show") std::cout << packetV.size() << std::endl;

    } while (input.size() > 0);
}
```

When I try compiling the code I get the fallowing errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\type_traits(1192): error C2070: 'char []': illegal sizeof operand
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\type_traits(1199): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::aligned_union<1,_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char []
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\memory(1731): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'aligned_union_t<1,char[]>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\memory(1778): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char []
1>        ]
1>c:\users\...\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\..\...\source.cpp(29): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<char []> std::make_shared<char[],int>(int &&)' being compiled
```

Could someone help me to understand the error and advice me on how to design the insertion and extraction of the data into the char * array by using smart pointers !?

Comment: Use std::vector or std::string!

Comment: s/`*data.get()`/`data.get()`

Comment: Since the other comment gives no motiviation for `std::vector`, I think the main criticism is that while you use `std::shared_ptr` it is not obvious how the data would be shared at all. If you actually want to encapsulate owning the data, then either use `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::vector`

Comment: Also you should note using `uint8_t` might be a more suitable type to represent arbitrary byte values with a message packet.

Comment: Before move to modern C++ practices you should learn how to follow old ones. For example data encapsulation and proper member initialization.

Answer (score 5):

`std::shared_ptr` is NOT specialized for use with arrays in the current standard version of C++. Support is expected to arrive in C++20.

In the meantime, you have a couple of options:

- Use `std::string`, which automatically manages dynamically-sized strings, and really should be your go-to default response when someone says "Save a bunch of characters in memory!"
- Use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. Unlike `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` IS specialized for arrays, which means the constructs you're trying to use will work with it.
- Use `std::vector<uint8_t>`. This is (nearly) equivalent to `std::string` in terms of the data it stores, but here, the usage is more verbose: the data isn't merely a string of characters, but specifically, it's raw binary data.

Comment: @tobi303 `std::string` is based on `signed char` IIRC.

Comment: @tobi303 `std::vector<uint8_t>` doesn't implicitly accept string-literals when assigning data, and unsigned values have fewer undefined-behaviors than signed values. And if you're getting nitpicky, `char` and `unsigned char` aren't *technically* the same types, even if their underlying representation is the same.

Comment: @tobi303 It's about conveying semantics. `std::string` says "This contains a *String*", whereas `std::vector<int8_t>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` says "This contains *Raw Binary Data*.". That distinction can make the *intent* of your code clearer and reduce the incidence of bugs.

Comment: semantics-wise i agree. I was refering to " the data isn't merely a string of characters, but specifically, it's raw binary data" and after thinking about it for a while I think I just misread that sentence (as it does not necesarrily claim that the raw data contained in a string is different from that contained in a vector). Thanks for your patience, I will remove the old comments

Comment: I was hoping I will save some memory using `std::shared_ptr`, having a pool of packets that will be distributed to all the clients. Having a `std::unique_ptr` will force me to make a copy of the pacet to each connection. That's why I hoped `std::share_ptr`'s will save me.